# Saving a new Opera Wand entry for a site previously dismissed

Tags: passwords, opera, automatic-logon

How do I save a new Wand entry in Opera for a site when I have already selected the "Never ask for this website" on a previous visit?

Answer (score 2):

*Works in Opera 10.51:*

1. Open the Password Manager.

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>.
   - Select "Forms" tab (Called "Wand" in versions before Opera 10).
   - Press "Password Manager" button.
2. Delete the web site from the list.
3. Reload the web site and enter your password.
4. The save password dialog will once again open.

[More info](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/how-to-save-password-in-wand)