# Add multiple passwords Opera's wand for a single site

Tags: passwords, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saving a new Opera Wand entry for a site previously dismissed](https://superuser.com/questions/132432/saving-a-new-opera-wand-entry-for-a-site-previously-dismissed)

We have mulitple Yahoo mail accounts.  Each time we've typed in a different set of ID & password, Opera's wand asked if we wanted it remembered, and we said yes.  Now when we go to the Yahoo site and hit the wand, we get a list of ID choices.  The problem is that I had to change the password for one of my email accounts.  This made the wand incorrect for that ID, so I deleted it.  Now it won't ask me again if I want the ID & password saved.  How do I add this back?  I thought about deleting all the Yahoo IDs, but I was afraid of the same thing happening to the rest.